# Auto expanding side column

Tags: xhtml, css

I am building a webpage and it has a div tag called content which has a CSS property of min-height: 200px;  I want to put in another div tag with a height of 100%, however, this does not work.  I want it to automatically grow so that it looks nice when content gets larger.   However I am unsure how to do this.

Any help is appreciated, but I want it to be XHTML strict and CSS3 compatible.

Trying to do something like this: [image: Something like this]

-They gray side bar, is what I wanted to do, it was added in paint, the rest I have already done with CSS3.

Comment: Also tried, height: inherit;, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the issue with height: 100%
Here is how I would do it using only css:

here it is:

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-color: #cbf;
    }

    #wrap {
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 900px;
    }

    #head {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #main {
        float: left;
        background-color: gray;
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width:200px;
        float: left;
        background-color: gray;
    }

    #content {
        float:left;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 200px;
        width: 700px;
    }

</style>
<title>
    example
</title>
</head> 

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="head">
        <h1>example site name</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            &nbsp;
            <p>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>
                ***</br></br></br>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also alternatively create the sidebar with

```
        #wrap {
            background: url('bg.png') repeat-y white;
        }
```

bg.png needs to be a 1 pixel high image that has the same width as the siderbar.
using css height 100% will not work in this case.

Hope this helps.